# Using full path of pip to install packge, failed

Tags: python

I have python2.7, python3.5 and winPython3.5 in my computer. Now I want to install package `gensim` to winPython3.5 in Windows command line. I use the full path of `pip` of winPython so I can install package in winPython. The command is

```
C:\Users\SHUYU LYU>"C:\Users\SHUYU LYU\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.2.3\python-3.5.2.amd64\Scripts\pip.exe" install gensim
```

But it still using python2.7 to install this package. The information in the console is showed below:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gensim in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.7.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): smart-open>=1.2.1 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.3 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): boto>=2.32 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): bz2file in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from smart-open>=1.2.1->gensim)
```

Could Anyone help with that? Since full path install should be work, I still do not figure out why it still uses `pip` of python2.7

Comment: try pip3 install gensim

Comment: @AjaySingh do not work

Comment: check if pip3 is install on your system?

Comment: @AjaySingh yes. Even it works, it can not help install packages in winpython..So, confused

Comment: the easiest is to eliminate Windows off the equation, it's always cumbersome to do programming on it (with probably single exception — everything that's in VS).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`python -m pip install <package name>`

or for `python3`:

`python3 -m pip install <package name>`

Comment: this can only install package in to python2.7 and python3.5.. I need to install it into winPython.

Comment: Apologies. I'm unable to help with that, then. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

if all else fails, try this:

```
click on icon "WinPython Command Prompt.exe"
type "pip install gensim"
```

Comment: I did this. It still shows that I installed gensim in python2.7

Comment: maybe there is a pythonpath variable that pollutes things. type "set" to check it. if it's  the issue, add a "set pythonpath="  in "script\env.bat "

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.